# io_blksize seems just return IO_BUFSIZE

Tags: unix, gnu-coreutils

I recent begin to read `cat.c` and was confused with the function `io_blksize`, this function defined as follow:

```
static inline size_t
io_blksize (struct stat sb)
{
   return MAX (IO_BUFSIZE, ST_BLKSIZE (sb));
}
```

and

```
enum { IO_BUFSIZE = 128*1024 };
#define DEV_BSIZE   4096
#define ST_BLKSIZE  (statbuf)      DEV_BSIZE
```

Now, the problem is `io_blksize` seemed always return `IO_BUFSIZE`, why not just defined the function:

```
static inline size_t
io_blksize (struct stat sb)
{
   return IO_BUFSIZE;
}
```

and in the macro `ST_BLKSIZE` what's the effect of parameters `sb`?`ST_BLKSIZE(sb)` seem to return `4096` always.

Comment: Maybe so auto configure can replace the #defines if appropriate ?

Comment: The relevant macros (particularly `ST_BLKSIZE()`) are operating-system dependent, and the last one can even return different values depending on the file/device at hand.

Answer (score 1):

`io_blksize()` returns at least 128KiB, but it may be larger in some situations on NFS for example. The reasoning behind the 128KiB value is detailed in [`src/ioblksize.h`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/9581c4b59d2e11cd090613cd300a833b4441d2b5/src/ioblksize.h#L24-L58).